# R data cleaning and imputation

Tags: r

I have  a .csv file with 5 columns (`Name`, `Age`, `Sal` (with $ symbol: for ex *$500*), `gender`, `marital status`).

I would like to:

1. Get rid of the $ symbol for the `sal` column.
2. Replace the age values that are missing with *NA*.

Comment: Please provide code so users can help you.

Comment: try `df$Sal <- gsub('\\$','',df$Sal)`. For better help you would need to update your question and provide reproducible example.

Answer (score 0):

First, I do not know if you have the CSV loaded. So firt,

```
df<-read.csv2("your_file.csv")
```

And then

```
df$sal<-gsub("$","",df$sal)
```

I do not know what do you mean with "missing" values, because if there are an empty value, R will put "NA" automatically.